# What is python-minimal?

Tags: command-line, python, gnome-terminal, python3

I had a problem that gave me an error message in the terminal whenever I tried executing a command. I checked a forum, and the most helpful solution instructed me to run this command:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install python3-minimal
```

So did I reinstall a file named 'Python3-minimal', or did I reinstall a 'minimal' version of python3?
I am new to all this, so please forgive me for such a dumb question.

Comment: Which exactly "an error message "? What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: If you are reinstalling `python3-minimal`, then you may have a serious problem. Your system NEEDS a working Python interpreter. Consider opening a new question detailing your problem.

Comment: Which exactly command forces you to reinstall `python3-minimal`?

Comment: @N0rbert after installing jupyter, my terminal stopped working. After I managed to get my terminal back, whenever I try to run some command, it says "bad interpreter: Too many levels of symbolic links". So I checked this forum and found someone else with this problem. I exactly executed the command in the most helpful answer which asked me to reinstall python-minimal and everything was back to normal. But I wanted to know what I just reinstalled. Because I thought I just installed a smaller version of Python because of the name.

Comment: @user535733 oh. But my system(including python) works fine as of now. Do you think I should still open a new question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package description:

> Minimal subset of the Python language (version 3.5)
> This package contains the interpreter and some essential modules. It can
> be used in the boot process for some basic tasks.
> See `/usr/share/doc/python3.5-minimal/README.Debian` for a list of the modules
> contained in this package.

You basically re-installed the packages that make the core of python v3. The README.debian does not tell what the essential modules are though ;).

Comment: Links like https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python3-minimal would be useful. But we really do not know actual problem. The 3.5 version looks incorrect for [actual Ubuntu releases](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=python3-minimal). The source of your citation is also needed.

Comment: but he does not want an answer for the error ;-) he wants to know what he did doing `sudo apt-get --reinstall install python3-minimal`

Comment: @Rinzwind so what I understood is python-minimal is basically a part of python3 that contains the interpreter and some other stuff. Is that right?

Comment: @hellohi yes that is correct